# Using a RecyclerView with data from LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-loadermanager

I have a `RecyclerView` that I use to display data fetched from a content provider using a `LoaderManager`. It works fine but I noticed some performance issues with my below implementation  when large data is loaded,There is a lag in displaying the data as I am using a `ViewPager` to load the `Fragment` that hosts this method

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Favorites = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
            Favorites.add(FavoritesModel.fromCursor(cursor));
    }
    adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),Favorites);
    favoritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

So I opted to do the following:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     ........
    adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(),Favorites);
    favoritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ........
```

And then on the onLoadFinished

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Favorites = new ArrayList<>();

    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
            Favorites.add(FavoritesModel.fromCursor(cursor));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
```

Using this nothing gets displayed. What is the issue since `onLoadFinished` is always called and I know its always called on the UI thread

Comment: Well @Blackbelt answered why you had empty list ... now about the lag ... it is simple ... **1st solution:(preffered) do not use model** (as iterating the cursor and creating models objects creates the lag)... use cursor directly in the Adapter(google for how to connect cursor with RecyclerView's adapter) .... **second solution is to** ... move current `onLoadFinished` code outside the main thread ...

Comment: That was something I thought of however the RecyclerView's adapter implements a filterable allowing for search widget to search, using a cursor in the adapter  would it be possible to do this

Comment: hmm filtering with Loaders is easy as using `restartLoader`

Comment: do you also have a `getLoaderManager().initLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, null, this);` in `onCreate(...)` ?

Comment: @k3b I have it in onActivityCreated

Comment: @Selvin Of the 1st solution and the 2nd which is better in terms of performance

Comment: 1st ... less memory footprint ... and of course 1st eliminates the lag ... 2nd just "hides" it

Comment: @Selvin you can offer this suggestion as an answer and I will accept it because of the two points you highlighted

Comment: I'm just curious, are you using the ContentProvider?

Comment: @Selvin Yes am using a ContentProvider

Comment: It's more like a hint not an answer ... try this: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59 ... of course i think that `MyListItem myListItem = MyListItem.fromCursor(cursor);
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(myListItem.getName());` is unnecesery ... you should rather use direct `viewHolder.mTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.TheColumnINeed))`

Answer (score 9):

I hope you got the correct answer. Well I had the same issue and did some good searching and finally came up with this.

This is the adapter

```
public class RecordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Cursor dataCursor;
    Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView time;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView distance;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public RecordAdapter(Activity mContext, Cursor cursor) {
        dataCursor = cursor;
        context = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View cardview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.record_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cardview);
    }

    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (dataCursor == cursor) {
            return null;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = dataCursor;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;
        if (cursor != null) {
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        String time = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(FitContract.RecordData.TIME));
        String date = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(FitContract.RecordData.DATE));
        String distance = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(FitContract.RecordData.DISTANCE));

        holder.time.setText(time);
        holder.date.setText(date);
        holder.distance.setText(distance);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (dataCursor == null) ? 0 : dataCursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

Then this is the fragment(you can use an activity as well)

```
public class RecordFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecordAdapter adapter;
    private int LOADER_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_layout, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_record);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_record);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("RECORD_FRAGMENT", "FAB");
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LineChartActivity.class));
            }
        });

        adapter = new RecordAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), FitContract.RecordData.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because here

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Favorites = new ArrayList<>();
```

you are either overriding the old reference of `Favorites` or you passed null in the first place. If you initialised `Favorites` before submitting the adapter, removing  `Favorites = new ArrayList<>();` should fix the empty list issue.

Comment: I am not initialising Favorites anywhere else except for when onLoadFinished is called. Doing this would cause multiple copies of the data to exist

Comment: I got mixed feelings about this answer ... *it is because here* ... **"it"** is not well defined in this answer as there are in fact 2 questions in question ... so this answer answer to the question about empty list ... not about the lag

Comment: @Selvin with *here*, I meant in the snippet. And I definitely missed the *lag* part

Comment: I meant that "It" should be replaced with "Empty list"